# I don't understand how an option is wrong in a multiple choise question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coordinate-systems

I dont understan why option E from this multiple choice question is accurate (option E is not the answer to the problem but was one of the options which are not false).

***I dont understand why its potential cannot be described by the formla.*** Does it have to do with that it is different coordinate system (cylindrical) and the dipole should be oriented in z direction? But can't that formula be used anyway if we somehow turn the formula or something?

---

**Problem:**

[image]

---

**The option:**
[image]

---

**From Collection of formulas:**

[image]

Comment: Your system is a physical dipole, not a point (pure) dipole. What is the potential between the charges (e.g. at and near the origin) in your system?

Comment: @robphy, V = 0 in y-z plane. But what is the differance between physical and pure dipole? EDIT: hmm I cant figure out how to calculate the potential at each of the point charges.

Comment: You should probably revise the title to be more descriptive of the physical content of the question.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common misconception. A dipole is NOT a set of two opposite charges, so you do not have a dipole in your configuration.

To be precise, you have a "physical dipole", two equal (in absolute value) and opposite ( sign) charges near each other. This is a usual configuration; but, as you have a finite numebr of point charges, you find the potential via superposition principle. The potential at one point is the sum of the one created by 1 and the one created by 2.

On the contrary, a "pure" dipole is an abstract idea. A dipole is an ideal **concept**, which is what appears as the first order term in the multipolar development of the potential.

In plain words, a pure dipole is a limit case of that you have. A pure dipole is two charges brought together, so near that their distance is exactly 0. If we want the distance to be 0, we better have charges tending to infinity, so that a dipole would have $q\cdot d = 0 \cdot \infty$.

$$dipole=\lim_{d\rightarrow 0\\ q\rightarrow +\infty} (q^+\text{---- }q^-)$$

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
Since the other answers are providing more of the answer,
let me reveal my interactive visualization.

As I mentioned in the comment to the OP, the "physical dipole" (composed of two equal-magnitude oppositely-signed point charges)
is not the same as the "pure [or point] dipole". For the same dipole moment $\vec p$, they disagree, especially near the dipole.

A plot reveals this disagreement.
At large distances (asymptotically), the two are in better agreement.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dis3e4xadc ( robphy - dipole - pure vs physical ) [assumes that the charges on the x-axis, are centered at the origin]

*[Play with the sliders to get some intuition. 
Fix $p$ so that when you change $d$, you must have $Q=p/d$. 

When do the potentials agree?]*

The green graph is the pure-dipole potential.
The dashed-lines are negative equipotentials.

[image: robphy-dipole-desmos-dis3e4xadc-equipotentials]

As I suggested in the original version of this answer,
one can plot these potential-functions for points along the x-axis.

[image: robphy-dipole-desmos-dis3e4xadc-V-vs-x]

---

Original answer:

Since this is tagged homework, I won't give the whole answer.

Given two point charges on the x-axis (following your givens):
 $q$ at $x=-(a/2)$ and $-q$ at $x= (a/2)$, 
compute the potential at (say) $x=(a/4)$.
Compare it to the value from the potential for the "point dipole" formula with $\vec p=q\vec a=(-q a) \hat x$ and $\vec R=(a/4)\hat x$.

Can you plot the potential of this two-point-charge example for points on the x-axis (vary x, fix y at 0)?
Can you plot the potential of the point dipole for points on the x-axis (vary x, fix y at 0)?

Comment: I had a Desmos plot to visualize what is going on... but because this is tagged homework, I held back.  But I see other answers are going ahead with giving the answer.

Comment: This is not homework, this is taken from an old test with answers key present. A moderator edited and tegged it as homework.

Comment: @Clone I have updated my answer with a Desmos visualization.

Answer (score 1):

The potential near the two charges would be found by adding two terms.  The formula you show is a good approximation if, R, is much larger than, a.